# Can AAA defend sea units

Tags: axis-and-allies

Can AAA defend sea units if land territory shares the same space as the sea territory? What if the transport landed units on that land territory - is it now 'on land' and defendable by AAA?

(Axis and Allies 1942 2nd Ed)

Answer (score 2):

AAA cannot defend sea territories.

From [the rules](https://axisallies.com/rules/axis-allies-rules-1942-2nd-edition.pdf):

> An Antiaircraft artillery (AAA) unit can fire only at an air unit when that unit attacks the territory containing that AAA unit. ... This AAA attack is made immediately before normal combat occurs in the territory containing the AAA unit.

Note that sea territory and land territories are always different territories, including in an amphibious assault:

> Each attacking air unit can participate in the sea battle or the attack on the coastal territory; it cannot do both.

AAA units on a transport can't shoot because they are cargo:

> Land units on a transport are cargo; they cannot attack or defend while at sea and are destroyed if their transport is destroyed.

Also, note that AAA guns cannot participate in an amphibious attack:

> An antiaircraft artillery unit cannot move during the Combat Move phase.

Finally, transports do not move onto land as part of an amphibious assault; only the units they are transporting:

> An amphibious assault takes place when you attack a coastal territory or island group from a sea zone by offloading land units from transports
> into that target territory.

Answer (score 0):

AAA guns can only defend the land territory they are on. If a transport unloads an AAA and then gets attacked the AAA gun cannot defend the transport. If a transport is transporting an AAA gun and gets attacked, the AAA gun is considered cargo and cannot help the defense.

Comment: Welcome to [boardgames.se]! I don't know the rules, so I can't tell whether this is correct, but do you have any references to back this up? If so, please [edit] them in your answer.